# error NG8001: 'tab' is not a known element

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular.
I follow the example at https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild but get the following errors. How to fix it?

```
import {Component, ContentChild, Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: 'pane'})
export class Pane {
  @Input() id!: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  template: `
    <div>pane: {{pane?.id}}</div>
  `
})
export class Tab {
  @ContentChild(Pane) pane!: Pane;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content-child',
  template: `
    <tab>
      <pane id="1" *ngIf="shouldShow"></pane>
      <pane id="2" *ngIf="!shouldShow"></pane>
    </tab>

    <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
  `,
})
export class ContentChildComponent {
  shouldShow = true;

  toggle() {
    this.shouldShow = !this.shouldShow;
  }
}
```

Error: src/app/content-child/content-child.component.ts:21:5 - error NG8001: 'tab' is not a known element:

1. If 'tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

21     
~~~~~

Error: src/app/content-child/content-child.component.ts:22:7 - error NG8001: 'pane' is not a known element:

1. If 'pane' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

22       <pane id="1" *ngIf="shouldShow">
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/content-child/content-child.component.ts:23:7 - error NG8001: 'pane' is not a known element:

1. If 'pane' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

23       <pane id="2" *ngIf="!shouldShow">
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The Angular version is 15.1.0.

Comment: Have you added both `Tab` and `Pane` component to the AppModule (root module) in the declaration array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yong Shun's hint fixed the errors. Thanks!

```
import { ContentChildComponent, Pane, Tab } from './content-child/content-child.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContentChildComponent,
    Pane,
    Tab
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```